# Simple Custom View Problem

Tags: android, view

edit 4:33pm 022111

I forgot to include my xml code. I'm so stupid.

Now I tried attrs to the super class and it still didn't help...

---

I tried searching for everything but no avail.

My code is very very simple.

The following includes everything I changed from the initial code I get from creating a project.

Thumbknightview.java

```
package com.google.www.Thumbknight;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
public class ThumbKnightView extends View{

public ThumbKnightView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public ThumbKnightView(Context context,  AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs); // edit 4:33pm 022111
}}
```

YoAndroid.java

```
package com.google.www.Thumbknight;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class YoAndroid extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//private ThumbKnightView tnv;


float x;
float y;
float lastx;
float lasty;
float maxspeed = 8;

int ipi = -1;
int firstfinger;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }}
```

main.xml

I know it might look stupid for experts but for me, it gave me 3+ hours of searching and reading. Please go easy on me.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? Does ThumbKnightView not show? If this is the case open main.xml layout and change the class of the view there from View to yourpackage.ThumbKnightView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify more details - what is your problem? Also, past relevant section of your layout XML.

The code, as such, looks mostly harmless. The only thing to remember is that when you chain the constructor call to super class, pass `AttributeSet` as well. You will have to also pass this `AttributeSet` to constructors of your child views.

For. e.g: if you are creating a Button you would say `new Button(activityContext,attrs);`

```
public ThumbKnightView(Context context,  AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
}}
```